# Conversion to pdf file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, print-production

I'm having trouble exporting a file to PDF. These bubbles are vectors, and when I print them directly from Illustrator, they are fine. However, when I convert them to a print-ready PDF, they end up being filled with white. Do you happen to know what the issue might be? I'm really at a loss.
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: OK hairlines like this are rendering errors. try zooming in do the lines stay about the same. If they do then its a conflation artefact

Comment: What Job Options are you using? Typically these hairlines are due to **flattening** for the PDF/X-1a format. (X-1a is a flat file format.) You *may* be able to simply use PDF/X-4 and the hairlines will disappear (X4 isn't a flat format). Check with the printer, some may not want PDF/X-4 files.